# Adding more than 1 variable to be called on php from a script

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a code like this (copied from a forum):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
      var ggg = $('#colsrc').val();

      $.post('students_query.php' ,{ggg:ggg}, function(data){
         $("#search_results").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

What it does is submit search query and return results without refresh.
Just to specify and to be clearer:

1. lets_search - the ID of a form where every data is taken.
2. colsrc - ID of a dropdown menu
3. students_query.php - the file where the submit action takes place, and the one that returns results after a query.
4. search_results - ID of a span tag where the returned results are shown

Everything works fine. My problem here is the variable created (ggg), which gets its value from colsrc, is the only one value being passed to students_query.php. What I want to happen is to pass 2 values to the students_query.php and I don't know which part of the code to edit or how to do it either.

Consider this data to be used:

1. ggg2 - another variable to be declared.
2. searchthis - id of another dropdown menu that contains the other value I want to pass to the php file.

I badly need 2 data to be passed on the php file for both of them will be used on a query that will determine the results to be returned. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another value in the post function parameters :

```
$.post('students_query.php' ,{
    ggg:ggg,
    ggg2: 'something'
}, function(data){
    $("#search_results").html(data);
});
```

Comment: i feel so terrible right now asking myself why haven't i thought of that,. xD. anyway thank you so much. it worked (y) :)

Answer (score 1):

JQuery post function accepts the data to be posted as a plain Javascript object or a string in its second parameter. When you want to post multiple values you can pass an object with multiple `key:value` pairs. In you case the code will look like this:

```
// $.post( url, data , success callback, expected dataType)

$.post('students_query.php', {
    ggg: ggg,                   // Add a comma here
    ggg2: 'value',              // Then add other data like this 
    searchthis: 'another value' // You can keep adding more
}, function(data) {
    $("#search_results").html(data);
});
```